# Android Unit Test and .so file [Linker Error]

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, .so

We are using different sets of .so files for debug and release versions.
`build.gradle` contains followign  things:

```
sourceSets {
debug {
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/debug']
        test.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/debug']
      }
release {
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/release']
        test.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/release']
        }
}
```

The .so files are within libs/debug and libs/release folder. Application works fine with apk created for both release and debug mode. But the android unit test cases fail with error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.test.mapp/app_files/.???" has bad ELF magic
    at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331)
```

What could be the reason? Wil it not work if we use both debug and release version of .so files by adding subfolders (debug/release) within libs folder?
One more thing to add here is that it works fine if I use one set (debug/release) of .so files in libs folder and use the following format in build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
test.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
}
```

Update[08-11-2016]:
The crash is even observed when the application debug apk is run on device or emulator.
The release apk is fine. Also the .so files are for different folders like debug/arm64-v8a,debug/mips etc. Based on this I guess the apk is not picking the .so files from libs/debug subfolders properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run unit test on the development machine then you obviously can't use native modules compiled for Android.

To use native modules in tested classes you must run your test on a device or emulator, creating instrumented unit test:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

Comment: Andorid Unit tests are run on device. It works fine if I use one set (debug or release) of .so files in libs folder. and use the following format :                                                                                                                          sourceSets {                                                                          main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']                                                test.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']                                                                                        }